# JTable Header Suddenly Changed its Column Name

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have designed jtable like this:

[image]

And when I compiled my Java GUI Netbeans program, it has no problem:

[image]

But after I press a JButton that I used this code to upload excel:

```
 private void b_browseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int column, row;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel File", "xls"));
    String al = file.getAbsolutePath();
    File excelFile = new File(al);
    if(!file.getName().endsWith("xls")){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
   "Pilih file Excel (.xls) saja!",
   "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
else
{
 if (excelFile.exists()) {
    try {
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheets()[0];
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(sheet.getRows(), sheet.getColumns());
        DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(null, JdlTabel);
        for (row = 0; row < sheet.getRows(); row++) {
            for ( column = 0; column < sheet.getColumns(); column++) {
                String content = sheet.getCell(column, row).getContents();
                model.setValueAt(content, row, column);
                data[row][column]=Double.parseDouble(content);
                n_data = sheet.getRows();
                k_data = sheet.getColumns(); 

            }
        }
        j_latih.setModel(model2);
        j_latih.setModel(model); //input data to Jtable
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no data!"); }
}  
    cek_kmeans=0;
    cek_data=1;//control tombol      
}
```

suddenly the table columns name changed like this:

[image]

So, what's wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> JTable Header Suddenly Changed its Column Name

```
DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel(null, JdlTabel);
```

You specify "null" for the column headers when you recreate the table model. so the default headings are used.

The solution is to either:

1. use the original column names when you recreate the model.
2. Don't recreate the entire model. Instead you can remove all the rows from the current model using `setRowCount(0)` of your `DefaultTableModel. Then you use the`addRow(...)`method of the`DefaultTableModel` to load the data back into the model one row at a time.

Comment: But the problem was, the jtable columns name was changed when I upload an excel file to be displayed.

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan, The table gets the column names from the TableModel. Every time you set a new model you get new column names. What do you expect to happen when you use "null" for the column names?